# Magento Your Checkout Progress Panel does not prepopulate information

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, checkout

I have been having this issue for quite some time now and have been trying to find the problem but have come to no solution. I am hoping you can give me some insight as to fix this problem.

My live site is working on 1.8.1.0 with a custom theme from Emthemes (latest version). PHP Version 5.4.28. I have development sites running 1.9.0.1 right now and the issue was not fixed in the recent release. I also have my development sites running PHP Version 5.5.12 with no issues (for people looking at upgrading to latest PHP).

First, I contacted my Custom Theme provider and they stated the issue was with Magento base files since the "Your Checkout Progress" Panel does not work with Base theme either. Has anyone else experienced this?

Next, I have looked at every Forum post related to this issue and no solution worked for me.

I have researched other sites operating on Magento platform and the "Your Checkout Progress" Panel is working perfectly.

I am under the assumption from reading forums that the issue is either caused by opcheckout.js, checkout.xml or onepage.phtml but I have applied all of the fixes I found and nothing seems to cure this issue. I have also tried reverting to the base files but still nothing.

If you visit my website and add a product to cart then Proceed to Checkout you will notice the "Your Checkout Progress" does not update as you walk through the steps for Checkout.

My website is [www.trucatchtraps.com](http://www.trucatchtraps.com)

Any help with fixing the "Your Checkout Progress" will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: hello, can you try to disable your custom theme and check with magento default theme, and also notice you are using one module for checkout, can you disable that.

Comment: okay it definitely has something to do with my custom theme. When I disabled custom theme by changing System->Config->Design->Package->Current Package Name to base, the checkout progress is working. Is there a reason the base design would not be showing? When I did this is changed to a white page with text.

Comment: hello, try to disable checkout.xml and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3383912 - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

I did not plan on trying this because when I talked to emthemes they said the issue was happening on the base theme as well. But when I disabled my theme, I noticed the "Your Checkout Progress" was actually working like it should.

After doing a little debugging, I noticed one of my extensions was overriding:

```
checkout/onepage/billing.phtml and shipping.phtml
```

So I hide these two files and brought the base billing.phtml and shipping.phtml just to make sure it would work, and voila everything was working like it should.

Then I noticed billing.phtml and shipping.phtml were extremely outdated (2009) so I updated with the new info from Magento 1.9.0.1 base files.

So I compared the two versions of the files and updated accordingly, I was still having issues. But what I did not realize is I have another extension working inside billing.phtml which was causing the issue in the first place. When I removed the 'Newsletter Opt-in' extension from billing.phtml everything was working again! So I have now moved the Newsletter Opt-in extension code to agreements.phtml and no problems.

FYI: Once I removed the Newsletter Opt-In code from my original outdated billing.phtml file, everything worked. So updating the file with the latest info from Magento 1.9.0.1 was not the solution but still needed to be done anyways.

This entire problem came from an extension that I did not even want to place on the website, but was told to do so...